# Status 403 on Jira connection with groovy

Tags: groovy, jira-rest-api

I have a script in Groovy to connect to Jira Rest Api and I received a Forbidden message on connection

I already have an implementation in java working fine and it is working when I use Postman. 
The

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7.1' )
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
try {
 def restClient = new RESTClient()
 def base64 = "${user}:${password}".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
 def response = restClient.get(
     uri: "https://url_to_jira",
     path: "/rest/api/2/project/MY_PROJECT_KEY",
     headers: [
       'Authorization':'Basic ${base64}'
     ]
   )
 } catch (Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

I expect to receive a result but I have a Forbidden message. 
I tried multiple libraries but the result is always the same.
I also used

```
http.auth.basic(myuser, mypassword)
```

But I have the same error. 
Again, it is working fine with Postman and my java code. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your authorization header must be enclosed in double quotes as it contains string interpolation.
example:
'Authorization':"Basic ${base64}"